# Can I say "be in someone else's custody"?

Tags: phrase-usage

> I feel some responsibility for not telling her the truth that she will be in her father's custody.

I did some research and it seems the common phrase is "remain in someone else's custody". I am not sure "be in someone else's custody" is right.

Comment: What doubts do you have about your sentence?

Comment: I checked on Fraze it. It shows "remain in someone else's custody" but not "be." I thought maybe it's wrong.

Comment: Please keep in mind "Is this sentence correct?" questions are proofreading requests and thus off-topic. Always tell us what exactly you are unsure about in your sentence.

Comment: **Custody** is a legal term. Her father will either be a policeman with the power to detain suspects in a cell – **in custody**, or be a parent to whom a court has granted the right to look after the child(ren) after a separation or divorce – **has custody**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **remain** in a state is to **continue** to be in that state.
So, if she is now in her father's custody, you could say "she will remain" in his custody. If she is not in his custody now, you should use "be".
You could also underline the change by saying she "will be placed in his custody".

Comment: Yes, I was not sure if saying "She is in her father's custody." Is correct.